# Mongoose Population issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to populate the records schema with users, So i can account for  a user for each record. However, i am only getting a blank array back.
Here are my schemas:

1.The Records schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const RecordsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    Title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: [{
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'users'
    }],
    Author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ISBN: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Review: {
        type: String
    },
    SelectedFile: {
        type: String
    },
    Likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    Date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = Records = mongoose.model('records', RecordsSchema ');
```

Here is the The user Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    records: [{
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'records'
    }],
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        immutable: true
    }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

The express route:

```
router.get('/all', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const records = await Records.find()
       .sort({ Date: -1})
            .populate('users')
            .exec()


        res.json(records);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(404).send('Server Error');
    }
});
```

Result:

```
{
    "users": [],
    "Likes": 0,
    "_id": "5fed8c12a4fb2c1e98ef09f6",
    "Title": "New Age",
    "Author": "Situma Prisco",
    "ISBN": "23422",
    "SelectedFile": "",
    "Review": "",
    "Date": "2020-12-31T08:30:10.321Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I'm getting a blank Array After populating.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How was that record saved?  Does the `users` field in the stored document contain anything?

Comment: it does. it contains whats on the users schema.  A user is currently logged in